# Excel Formula to find the first non-NA column in a row, from right to left

Tags: excel

Data looks like this:

```
    A     B     C     D     E     F     G         ...           offset
1  #N/A   #N/A  12    14    #N/A  #NA   #N/A                    -3
```

Right now I have a long nested formula that looks like this:

```
=IF(ISNA(G1)=FALSE,0,IF(ISNA(F1)=FALSE,-1,IF(ISNA(E1)=FALSE,-2,IF(ISNA(D1)=FALSE,-3,IF(ISNA(C1)=FALSE,-4,IF(ISNA(B1)=FALSE,-5,IF(ISNA(A1)=FALSE,-6,-7)))))))
```

I am constantly editing and adding new columns which makes updating the forumla a pain in the butt.  Is there an easier way to automate the formula so that it can find the column of the first non #N/A entry when looking from right to left?  So that when I add new columns between F and G, for instance, it will expand it scope without me having to?

I would like to avoid `VB` if possible here and keep this as a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=aggregate(14, 7, column(a:z)/(A1:Z1<>""), 1)
=address(1, aggregate(14, 7, column(a:z)/(A1:Z1<>""), 1))
=index(1:1, 0, aggregate(14, 7, column(a:z)/(A1:Z1<>""), 1))
```

The 0, -1, -2 result is just maths.